# How not to trigger ng-click of TR when I only need the ng-click of Checkbox inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have this ng-click on a Table Row which opens a modal.

```
<tr ng-repeat="cpPortfolioItem in cpPortfolioTitles"
            ng-click="viewIndividualDetailsByTitle(cpPortfolioItem)">
```

Now I have this ng-click on the checkbox inside the Table Row

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectTitle($index)">
```

When I click on the checkbox, modal opened and also it executes the function of ng-click on the checkbox. How can I prevent modal from opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop event [propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Try like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectTitle($index);$event.stopPropagation()">
```

or can use like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectTitle($index,$event);">
$scope.selectTitle=function($index,$event){
  $event.stopPropagation()
}
```